# Data.Frame Format for Bland-Altman with Levels for Coloring

Tags: r

I am struggling finding a solution for data representation for drawing a Bland-Altman plot (with blandr/epade or other packages) where I can colorize the different methods differently. 
I would like to compare measurements taken by a smartphone-accelerometer vs. a video analysis. Therefore, I read all the data in and represented them in the long format.

```
Date Participant Rater Machine_ASVZ   Machine Set Contraction_Mode Time_Video Smartphone Time_Smartphone
3 2019.01.26          CV    CV           A1 LEG PRESS   1             Con1       1340          1            1650
4 2019.01.26          CV    CV           A1 LEG PRESS   1             Ecc1       2580          1            2450
5 2019.01.26          CV    CV           A1 LEG PRESS   1             Con2       1160          1            1350
6 2019.01.26          CV    CV           A1 LEG PRESS   1             Ecc2       2300          1            2100
7 2019.01.26          CV    CV           A1 LEG PRESS   1             Con3       1220          1            1400
8 2019.01.26          CV    CV           A1 LEG PRESS   1             Ecc3       2120          1            1950
```

Rater is a factor of two Raters that analyzed independently Time_Video and Smartphone is a factor of two Smartphone measurements (Time_Smartphone).

As Bland-Altman plots favor two vectors (one for each method measurements), I cast and mutate the data.frame so that I calculate the mean of the two raters video analysis (Time_Video) and the two smartphone measurements (Time_Smartphone):

```
 Date Participant Machine_ASVZ       Machine Set Contraction_Mode Time_Video_CV Time_Video_GRFD Time_Smartphone_1 Time_Smartphone_3 Rater_Mean Smartphone_Mean
1 2019.01.26          CV           A4 LEG EXTENSION   1             Con1          1160            1140              1300              1300       1150            1300
2 2019.01.26          CV           A4 LEG EXTENSION   1             Ecc1          2340            2320              2250              2300       2330            2275
3 2019.01.26          CV           A4 LEG EXTENSION   1             Con2          1160            1160              1200              1150       1160            1175
4 2019.01.26          CV           A4 LEG EXTENSION   1             Ecc2          2340            2360              2300              2300       2350            2300
5 2019.01.26          CV           A4 LEG EXTENSION   1             Con3          1220            1200              1250              1250       1210            1250
6 2019.01.26          CV           A4 LEG EXTENSION   1             Ecc3          2020            2000              2000              2000       2010            2000
>
```

Now, I don't know how to insert the levels (Video, Smartphone) for colorizing the Bland-Altman plot so, that video and smartphone measurements are distinguishable.

```
bland_altman_plot<- blandr.draw(as.numeric(unlist(dplyr::select(filter(melt_subset, Source=="Rater_Mean"),"Time"))), as.numeric(unlist(dplyr::select(filter(melt_subset, Source=="Smartphone_Mean"),"Time"))), method1name = "Method 1",
                 method2name = "Method 2",
                 plotTitle = paste("Bland-Altman-Plot ",i, sep=""),
                 sig.level = 0.95, LoA.mode = 1, annotate = FALSE, ciDisplay = TRUE,
                 ciShading = FALSE, normalLow = FALSE, normalHigh = FALSE,
                 lowest_y_axis = FALSE, highest_y_axis = FALSE, point_size = 2,
                 overlapping = FALSE, plotter = "ggplot2", x.plot.mode = "means",
                 y.plot.mode = "difference", plotProportionalBias = TRUE,
                 plotProportionalBias.se = TRUE, assume.differences.are.normal = TRUE)
```

How can I carry along a levels in a wide format so that colorizing by factor in a plot such as the Bland-Altman plot using the blandr package?

[image]

Comment: Bland-Altman plot is designed to assess the agreement of two methods. The x-axis is the mean of the measurements from the two methods and the y-axis is their difference, so both x and y-axis contain combined information of these two methods. I don't think you can/should "distinguish" these two methods in a Bland-Altman plot.

Comment: I agree with @HCQ. Looking at your graph, it might be worth plotting the difference of the logs of the measurements on the y-axis.  There is also a variation of the Bland-Altman plot where the limits of agreement are sloping.  Check out their 1999 paper, you can find it on the net. Bland, J. M., & Altman, D. G. (1999). Measuring Agreement in Method Comparison Studies — A Review. Statistical Methods in Medical Research, 8, 135–160.

Comment: Good point. Thank you very much. I am using Blandr Package which takes two vectors as input and draws differences. But there is no log-transformation possible. Atleast not with my poor knowledge of R :(

Answer (score 0):

Almost in two cases, already published, I solved drawing problem manually. You can draw the first set of data with your preferred plotting function (blandaltmanleh or blandr) and then add points. If you are not satisfied with self produced BA lines, the last alternative was to calculate BA stats for all data, plot manually the margins and lines and then plots the points in two steps/ color.